# add multiple text box linked to different control source

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add different text boxes with different control sources values and change when the values are changed I am looping through different number of text boxes that I may have to add to a userform. The problem that I face is that the the Control Source does not allow to be changed every time I loop and create a new text box to be connected to a new cell.

```
    Set qtextbox1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1", "Uquantity_TextBox_"  & i)
     Set myrangeused = Cells(userow + i, usecol)
     add = myrangeused.Address
     With qtextbox1
        .ControlSource = "'Lookup Lists'!F4"
```

the code works when i add a particular cell but does not link different taxt boxes to different sources.

Answer (score 0):

thank you if anyone tried this. i got a solution for the above stated problem. the control source can be made dynamic if instead of

```
     With qtextbox1
    .ControlSource = "'Lookup Lists'!F4"
```

we

```
       With qtextbox1
      .ControlSource = add <<~~ address of the targetcell `
```